# Insertion sort not printing all values in C

Tags: c, sorting, insertion-sort

Insertion sort is not working, it is only printing some of the values. Does anyone know what I can do to fix it?

```
void insertion(int Array[], int n) {
   for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      int j = i;
      while (j >= 0 && Array[j] < Array[j - 1]) {
         int temp = Array[j];
         Array[j] = Array[j - 1];
         Array[j - 1] = temp;
         j--;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The code presented is not printing at all. Please produce a [mcve]

Comment: When j is 0 you will use negative array indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test in the inner loop is incorrect: when `j == 0` you read and possibly modify the element at offset `-1`, which has **undefined behavior**, possibly causing the incorrect output, but since you did not post the output code, there might be other problems there.

Here is a modified version:

```c
void insertion(int Array[], int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0 && Array[j] < Array[j - 1]; j--) {
            int temp = Array[j];
            Array[j] = Array[j - 1];
            Array[j - 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insertion Sort: Idea 
 Similar to how most people arrange a hand of poker cards 
 Start with one card in your hand
 Pick the next card and insert it into its proper sorted order 
 Repeat previous step for all cards
[image]